# Would it be meaningful, if I concatenate LSTM output with CNN output?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am trying to boost the performance of [a single-frame object detection network](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6210968/) with multiple frames input.

In side the network I have added an ConvLSTM module with 200 channel. The modified network couldn't achieve the same-level performance of original network.

```py
#Feature_200 means: "a feature map with 200 channels"

#original network pipeline:
Encoder-> Feature_200 -> Decoder

#modify Nr.1:
Encoder-> Feature_200 -> ConvLSTM -> Feature_200 -> Decoder

#want to implement:
Encoder-> Feature_200 -> ConvLSTM -> Feature_100 --concat---> Feature_300 -> Decoder
                |                                  |
                 ------short cut---> Feature_200 --
```

So I am considering concatenate the ConvLSTM results to the original network's feature map. Would this structure be helpful to improve the performance?

(Ps. I'm not sure if it's correct to refer the module with "encoder" and "decoder")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ConvLSTM as a feature extractor and use the concatenated features as input for some machine learning classifier like Random Forest or SVM.